# Extracting multiple photos from a single quickly

Tags: photos, preview, macos, crop

I recently went through the process of scanning old photo albums (in an effort to preserve them longer digitized). I would place 2/3/4 photos on the scanner. Now I need to extract the single photos. It would also help if there was an application to quickly recognize the rectangles.

N.B.: I'm running the latest beta of Sierra.

Comment: Have you tried using Photoshop? I believe there's a way to do it in there.

Comment: @NoahL Afraid I don't have the budget for Photoshop

Comment: if you think it's worth trying, they have a 30-day free trial (you don't need to enter a credit card number or anything)

Answer (score 1):

You could use ImageMagick or NetPbm tools to crop the photos from a script, but it isn't going to automatically detect the rectangle edges.

Lay out your photos in roughly the same place every time you scan them. Leaving a small gap between the photos would give you a safety buffer; the resulting scanned/cropped photos will just have a white border around them.

Answer (score 0):

A couple of Mac OS apps do this: [Snip](https://apps.apple.com/us/app/sniptag-crop-caption-photos/id1538901870?mt=12) (if you only need batch cropping) and [SnipTag](https://www.sniptagapp.com) (for batch-cropping and editing image metadata). The workflow for both these apps is as follows:

- Capture 3-4 photos per scan using a scanner or digital camera
- Save all such scans in a folder on your Mac
- Import all the scans as a batch into the app
- All the photos are cropped and saved as individual photos
- Export the photos to Mac, external HD or cloud storage

[Disclosure: I do customer service at AIL, developer of these apps.]